# How do I get my code to continue receiving user input until the password matches the parameters?

Tags: java

I am trying to get my code to loop until the user input meets the parameters of the password "Please enter a password with the following criteria: 
    Password must contain at least 8 characters, 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter,1 number

```
Password must not contain the word 'password' , spaces (' ') or  special characters");
```

I am struggling to get my do-while loop to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

code snippet:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class PasswordValidation
{
public static void main(String[]args){

  boolean valid = false;
  System.out.println("Please enter password with the following criteria");
  System.out.println("Password must contain atleast 8 characters, 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter,1 number");
  System.out.println("Password must not contain the word 'password' , spaces (' ') or  special characters");

  do {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   String password = input.nextLine();




            if (password.length() >= 8)
            {
                    System.out.println("Password must be atleast 8 characters in length.");
                    valid = false;
            }

            String upperCaseChars = "(.*[A-Z].*)";
            if (!password.matches(upperCaseChars ))
            {
                    System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one upper case letter");
                    valid = false;
            }
            String lowerCaseChars = "(.*[a-z].*)";
            if (!password.matches(lowerCaseChars ))
            {
                    System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one lower case letter");
                    valid = false;
            }
            String num = "(.*[0-9].*)";
            if (!password.matches(num ))
            {
                    System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one number.");
                    valid = false;
            }
            String specialChar = "(.*[,~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),-,_,=,+,[,{,],},|,;,:,<,>,/,?].*$)";
            if (password.matches(specialChar ))
            {
                    System.out.println("Password should not contain special character");
                    valid = false;
            }
            if (password ==  "password")
            {
                    System.out.println("Password Should not be 'password'");
                    valid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                    valid = true; 
                    System.out.println("Password is valid.");
            }
        }
    } while valid = false;
```

}

Comment: for string comparison in java use `str1.equals(str2)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
boolean valid = false;
    do {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String password = input.nextLine();


        if (password.length() >= 8) {
            System.out.println("Password must be atleast 8 characters in length.");
            valid = false;
        }

        String upperCaseChars = "(.*[A-Z].*)";
        if (!password.matches(upperCaseChars)) {
            System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one upper case letter");
            valid = false;
        }
        String lowerCaseChars = "(.*[a-z].*)";
        if (!password.matches(lowerCaseChars)) {
            System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one lower case letter");
            valid = false;
        }
        String num = "(.*[0-9].*)";
        if (!password.matches(num)) {
            System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one number.");
            valid = false;
        }
        String specialChar = "(.*[,~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),-,_,=,+,[,{,],},|,;,:,<,>,/,?].*$)";
        if (password.matches(specialChar)) {
            System.out.println("Password should not contain special character");
            valid = false;
        }
        if (password.equals("password")) {
            System.out.println("Password Should not be 'password'");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            valid = true;
            System.out.println("Password is valid.");
        }
    } 
    while (!valid);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your else statement only checks against the final if statement. I would remove the else statement and declare valid as true at the begining of the loop

```
do {
              valid =true;
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
           String password = input.nextLine();
                    if (password.length() >= 8)
                    {
                            System.out.println("Password must be atleast 8 characters in length.");
                            valid = false;
                    }

                    String upperCaseChars = "(.*[A-Z].*)";
                    if (!password.matches(upperCaseChars ))
                    {
                            System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one upper case letter");
                            valid = false;
                    }
                    String lowerCaseChars = "(.*[a-z].*)";
                    if (!password.matches(lowerCaseChars ))
                    {
                            System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one lower case letter");
                            valid = false;
                    }
                    String num = "(.*[0-9].*)";
                    if (!password.matches(num ))
                    {
                            System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one number.");
                            valid = false;
                    }
                    String specialChar = "(.*[,~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),-,_,=,+,[,{,],},|,;,:,<,>,/,?].*$)";
                    if (password.matches(specialChar ))
                    {
                            System.out.println("Password should not contain special character");
                            valid = false;
                    }
                    /*Strings cant use comparators like ==*/
                    if (password.equalsIgnoreCase("password"))
                    {
                            System.out.println("Password Should not be 'password'");
                            valid = false;
                    }
            } while (!valid); 
            System.out.println("Password is valid");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store all the String values before the do-while loop, then it takes less computation time. Because it does not need to initialize the string variable every time. And also if you use the else-if ladder, then it also reduces the execution time. It should be something like this:

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean valid;
        String upperCaseChars = "(.*[A-Z].*)";
        String lowerCaseChars = "(.*[a-z].*)";
        String num = "(.*[0-9].*)";
        String specialChar = "(.*[,~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),-,_,=,+,[,{,],},|,;,:,<,>,/,?].*$)";
        System.out.println("Please enter password with the following criteria");
        System.out.println("Password must contain atleast 8 characters, 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter,1 number");
        System.out.println("Password must not contain the word 'password' , spaces (' ') or  special characters");

        do {
            String password = input.nextLine();

            if (password.length() < 8) {
                System.out.println("Password must be atleast 8 characters in length.");
                valid = false;
            }

            else if (!password.matches(upperCaseChars)) {
                System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one upper case letter");
                valid = false;
            }

            else if (!password.matches(lowerCaseChars)) {
                System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one lower case letter");
                valid = false;
            }

            else if (!password.matches(num)) {
                System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one number.");
                valid = false;
            }

            else if (password.matches(specialChar)) {
                System.out.println("Password should not contain special character");
                valid = false;
            }
            else if (password == "password") {
                System.out.println("Password Should not be 'password'");
                valid = false;
            } else {
                valid = true;
                System.out.println("Password is valid.");
            }
        }
        while (valid == false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your else clause is working only for the last if clause. So add a new if clause to check all the conditions.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class PasswordValidation {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
         boolean valid = false;
         System.out.println("Please enter password with the following criteria");
         System.out.println("Password must contain atleast 8 characters, 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter,1 number");
         System.out.println("Password must not contain the word 'password' , spaces (' ') or  special characters");
    // Password must not contain the word 'password' , spaces (' ') or special
    // characters");
    // Password must contain atleast 8 characters, 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase
    // letter,1 number

    do {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String password = input.nextLine();

        if (password.length() <= 8) {
            System.out.println("Password must be atleast 8 characters in length.");
            valid = false;
        }

        String upperCaseChars = "(.*[A-Z].*)";
        if (!password.matches(upperCaseChars)) {
            System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one upper case letter");
            valid = false;
        }

        String lowerCaseChars = "(.*[a-z].*)";
        if (!password.matches(lowerCaseChars)) {
            System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one lower case letter");
            valid = false;
        }

        String num = "(.*[0-9].*)";
        if (!password.matches(num)) {
            System.out.println("Password should contain atleast one number.");
            valid = false;
        }

        String specialChar = "(.*[,~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),-,_,=,+,[,{,],},|,;,:,<,>,/,?].*$)";
        if (password.matches(specialChar)) {
            System.out.println("Password should not contain special character");
            valid = false;
        }

        if (password == "password") {
            System.out.println("Password Should not be 'password'");
            valid = false;
        }

        if ((password.length() > 8) && (password.matches(upperCaseChars)) && (password.matches(lowerCaseChars))
                && (password.matches(num)) && (!password.matches(specialChar)) && (password != "password")) {
            valid = true;
            System.out.println("Password is valid.");
        }

    } while (!valid);

}
```

}